# media center extended

Tags: mediacenter

Where can I find resources related to writing your own media center extender client - i.e. an application that will run on another machine at home and remotely render vista's media center on it, allowing to stream movies, live tv etc
Thanks,
Gil

Answer (score 0):

At least some of the services are based around protocols [DLNA](http://www.dlna.org/industry/why_dlna/key_components/) for the discovery of available services

Answer (score 0):

If you write your Media center application and stock to MCML (Media center markup loanguage) it will run on the extender anyway without any additional work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.  That would be called a softsled.  Microsoft have not made any of the Media Center framework information available to anybody besides preferred clients (Linksys, Samsung, etc.) and has not done it since Vista.

The media center extenders actually does not use DLNA yet but they created a remote-desktop session where they connected to the media center server and streamed video.  This is why you see users listed MCS-YOURCOMPNAME-0001.

The only media center extender left is Xbox 360.  Sorry to be a downer.

http://www.geektonic.com/2009/05/microsoft-media-extenders-what.html